# Autocomplete Jquery UI... Bug with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I've got a problem with my autocomplete script... If I use my json file all my data are displayed but autocomplete doesn't work.. In contrast, if I use the table NPA, it works...

Someone can help me about this problem ? Thanks !

My autocomplete.php

```
var NPA = 'npa.json'; 
var NPA2 = [{"value": "1700","label": "NewYork City"},{"value": "1701","label": "Chicago"}];

$('#tags').autocomplete({
source: NPA2,
minLength: 1
});
```

My npa.json :

```
[{"value": "1700","label": "NewYork City"},{"value": "1701","label": "Chicago"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content of `NPA` should be the string of `npa.json`. And not the content of this file.

Yo should [load the content of the json file](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/):

```
var NPA = 'npa.json';
$.getJSON(NPA, function(data) {
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source: data,
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```